# Thinkpad T60 flickering screen

Tags: video, laptop, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) on my Lenovo Thinkpad T60.  I randomly get screen flickerings on my screen.  Once it happens, it doesn't go away (unless I reboot my computer).  I would describe the flickering as horizontal color lines appearing throughout the screen where the text is difficult to read everywhere.

I ran the following to see what video card is installed:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Mobility X1400
```

My question is: **what's wrong and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now running Ubuntu 11.04 on my Thinkpad T60, and the screen flickering issue doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, sounds like [Bug #541501](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/541501) which is still open.

I have a similar problem on a Thinkpad T60 with ATI Radeon Mobility X1300. None of the workarounds suggested in the comments of the linked bug entry (`modeset=0` and/or `new_pll=0` parameters to the `radeon` module, a newer mainline kernel) seem to completely make the problem go away for me – however, some of them seem to help a bit though.

Comment: +1 sounds exactly like my problem is.  YouTube video seems to confirm it too.  Thanks for link.