# How do I troubleshoot crazy screen flickering?

Tags: 16.04, graphics

I'm running 16.04 on an X1 Carbon that I've had for a few years. More than a few. But it's been trouble free this whole time. This afternoon the screen started to do weird flickering things. It draws wacky shapes, slices everything into triangles and snaps them back. I'm seeing this on the external monitor that I've used for the last month as well as on my laptop monitor.

Based on reading [Thinkpad T60 flickering screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2336/thinkpad-t60-flickering-screen) (slightly different hardware) I did `lspci | grep VGA` which says

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

It's occasional and very random. Sometimes a window in the background (terminal, I think) will flash blue for a second. Sometimes weird triangle shards radiate from my cursor.

What else should I be checking/looking at to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Well its not a cabling or signal issue. It could be a driver issue but more likely its because of memory corruption due to faulty RAM or bad configuration like overclocked ram.

Comment: If you take a screenshot, are the artifacts shown in the screenshot? (If so, please add to question. If not, please add photograph of monitor displaying problems you are describing.) Also, have you recently changed any settings or updated any packages? Anything having to do with the video driver, compositing, desktop/window manager (what desktop are you using?)... Changes from X.org to Wayland, or vice versa.

Comment: I restarted and the whole issue is gone. But how would I find out if my ram is overclocked, or faulty?